# React-Trying to append new item on setState object but just adding last one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a array with objects(products)[{},{}] and im trying to append this objects value's to another objects key-values like

```
products.map((e) => {
   setProductPrices({
      ...productPrices,
      [e.title]: e.unitPrice,
   });
});
```

but it is setting just second key.

my console:

```
first

second

{second: 15}
```

Comment: Maybe you could give some more context. Show us how the `productPrices` state has been defined. Show us the statements calling `console.log`. Without this stuff, its very hard to understand what you're talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, because the `setProductPrices` is asynchronous and so the `productPrices` is not updated immedietely. So you are reusing the starting `productPrices` on each iteration, and it only keeps the last one.

A quick fix (***you should not use this***) would be to use the version where you provide a function that has access to the previous state of the state

```
products.map((e) => {
   setProductPrices((prevPrices) => ({
      ...prevPrices,
      [e.title]: e.unitPrice,
   }));
})
```

---

But the more correct way, would be to generate a local version and do a single update at the end

```
const updatedPrices = {...productPrices};
products.forEach((e) => {
   updatedPrices[e.title]= e.unitPrice;
})
setProductPrices(updatedPrices);
```